# sql query to find most viewed actor by the customer in the database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i would like to find the actor who is viewed most by the customer. There can be a scenario where we can get actor having same number of views but we will return the top one.

Here is what I have tried but it not working as intended:

```
SELECT count(film_actor.actor_id), actor.first_name, actor.last_name 
FROM actor INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
GROUP BY film_actor.actor_id
```

Here is the database schema:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at actual film rentals:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS viewings, actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name 
FROM actor INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
INNER JOIN inventory ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id
INNER JOIN rental ON inventory.inventory_id = rental.inventory_id
GROUP BY actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
ORDER BY viewings DESC
LIMIT 1
```